# Java log4j2 timestamp during Daylight saving issue

Tags: java, logging, timezone, log4j, websphere-liberty

Recently I came across this situation where I have two different types of logs in the server. One is directly using the JDK system time and displaying it another one is using log4j in WLP.

The one which is using log4j is logging time one hour early than the current system time in Austin machines as compared to Asia machines (Assuming time zone issue) (the log without log4j implementation is showing the correct time).

The situation may have occurred due to Day Light Saving. I looked into the log4j2.xml for its  tag implementation and found something as follows
current pattern

```
**<pattern>%d{ISO8601} [%-50.50t] %marker [%p] %F:%L %C.%M() %n......MDC: %X %n......NDC: %x %n......MSG: %-70.70m %n</pattern>**
```

I tried to change it to the format

```
**<pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%t-%x-%-5p-%-10c:%m%n</pattern>**
```

to see if it works.
And voila! It started logging the correct time.
[But the situation of restart are different, once completed restarted the machine & once just restarted the WLP, Just after restarting the WLP we found the log time stamp is almost similar to machine time stamp.]

However, I think ISO8601 format is more appropriate to keep.

Have you guys came across such situation or know some solution to it except the one which I tried.
The Time zone information of the server
Clock : UTC
Time Zone : America/Chicago

log4j Version used : log4j-2.x

So, again if you know any solution where daylight saving time can be automatically processed and display the right time with sync. to the current system time or is there any fix available in the latest log4j versions if any, please inform

Thanks

Comment: The above stated solution is only working for the UTC timezone.

Comment: We woke up today to the same problem. Apparently DST ended yesterday in the US where our servers are.
Unfortunately we just upgraded to Log4j2 2.6.2 last week. Is there a solution for this other than restarting all our processes that are using log4j?